# Firewire 400 to 800 to Thunderbolt - is it hot swappable?

Tags: firewire, thunderbolt

I've finally managed to connect a Saffire Pro 40 sound card to my Asus Rog G751 laptop via the Apple thunderbolt to FireWire, and then a 400-800 bilingual FireWire cable to the Saffire pro.

But I've fried a FireWire port before, though not with Thunderbolt. And was wondering how the best practice is for plugging and unplugging this device to my laptop?

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar question regarding a Saffire Pro 24 audio interface connected to a 2014 MacBook Pro Retina via a Firewire 400 to 800 cable and a Firewire 800 to Thunderbolt adapter as so:

[Hot pluggable configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxBkY.jpg)

I got this answer when I asked Focusrite Tech Support:
'Yes, you can hot plug the Saffire when you have it connected to the thunderbolt to firewire adapter, proving you only remove the adapter from the computer and not the firewire cable from the adapter or Saffire.'